# What is the best method to sniff bluetooth on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: bluetooth, home-automation

Just bluetooth sniffing, what software does that, has to work on a Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 3):

BlueZ is the official Bluetooth stack for Linux kernel-based family of operating systems. Its goal is to program an implementation of the Bluetooth wireless standards specifications for Linux.

It has command line tools of `bluetoothctl` and `btmgmt` that provide the ability to scan for other devices within range.

To interact with BlueZ from a programming language then there is a set of APIs documented at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

There is an example in the source tree of using those APIs to scan for devices:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-discovery